# First Order Time-Variant System : Picard Method

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, picard-scheme

I looking at a time variant first order system. I am trying to prove that a sequence of functions $x^{[k]}(t)$ generated using Picard iterations converges uniformly on some interval $[0,T]$.

Given:

$\dot{x}(t)=A(t)x(t)$ where $x(0)=x_0$

$x(t)=x∈R^n$ where $A(t)$ is a $n×n$ matrix

Assume there exists $M$ such that $||A(t)||\le M$ for all $t\ge 0$ and that $A(t)$ is a piecewise continuous function. Show that, for any $T > 0$, a solution exists in the interval $[0,T]$.

I know that $x(t)=x_0+\int^t_0A(τ)x(τ) dτ$ must be satisfied if the solution does indeed exist.

I am supposed to use Picard iterations to prove this, which I am not familiar with yet. But I know that they are of the form: $x^{[k+1]}=x_0+\int^t_0A(τ)x^{[k]}(τ) dτ$. Where $x^{[0]}(t)=x_0$

Can I use the standard Picard proof to prove this or do I need to start somewhere else?

I was also asked to show that this method satisfies

$|x^{[k+1]}(t)-x^{[k]}(t)|\le |x_0| $$\frac{π^{k+1}(t)}{(k+1)!}$ where $π(t)=\int^t_0||A(τ)||dτ$.

I have no idea where to start with this, but hopefully it will become clearer once I finish the first part.

Comment: Looking at the standard existence proof might be helpful as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are to use is a generalized version of the Banach fixed point theorem. If $F$ is a fixed-point operator on some complete space $X$ and each iterated composition $F^m$ has a Lipschitz constant $L_m$ on the whole of $X$ and $\sum_m L_m<\infty$, then the fixed point iteration converges to the unique fixed point.

What you are to show is that for $X=C([0,T])$ and $F$ the Picard iteration, you get $L_m=\frac{\pi(T)^m}{m!}$ so that $\sum_{m=1}^\infty L_m=e^{\pi(T)}-1<\infty$. This is proved via induction. The induction claim is that
$$
\|F^n(x)-F^n(y)\|_{C([0,t]}\le \frac{\pi(t)^m}{m!}\|x-y\|_{C([0,t]}
$$
where
$$
\|u\|_{C([0,t]}=\max_{s\in [0,t]}|u(s)|
$$
is the usual supremum norm on the space of continuous functions restricted to the indicated domain $[0,t])$.

In the induction proof for the step from $n=k-1$ to $n=k$ you compute, using $\pi'(t)=\|A(t)\|$,
\begin{align}
\|F^k(y)(t)-F^k(x)(t)\|
&=\left\|\int_0^tA(s)[F^{k-1}(y)(s)-F^{k-1}(x)(s)]\,ds\right\|
\\
&\le\int_0^t\|A(s)\|\,\left\|F^{k-1}(y)(s)-F^{k-1}(x)(s)\right\|\,ds
\\
&\le\int_0^t\pi'(s)\frac{\pi(s)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\|y-x\|_{C([0,s])}\,ds
\\
&\le \frac{\pi(t)^k}{k!}\|y-x\|_{C([0,t])}\le \frac{\pi(T)^k}{k!}\|y-x\|_{C([0,T])}
\end{align}

Comment: Ok, I think this makes sense. However, I am wondering how you got from your 3rd to last line to your 2nd to last. How do we know the relationship between these expressions?

Comment: Is the question about $\int_0^t\pi(s)^{k-1}\pi'(s)\,ds=\frac1k\pi(s)^k$ or about $\|u\|_{C([0,s])}\le\|u\|_{C([0,t])}$ for $s\le t$?

Comment: Where you first introduce pi, so the first part of your comment. I saw you edited your response to make it a clearer. Thanks!